# Electron block using shortcut CTRL + minus button

Tags: electron

I need block in my app in Electron shortcut `CTRL` + `-`.
I write in main.js:

```
globalShortcut.register("CmdOrCtrl+-", () => false);
```

But it's not working.

If I have e.g.:

```
globalShortcut.register("CmdOrCtrl+R", () => false);
```

then shortcut `CTRL` + `R` is blocked correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use numsub instead of '-' directly.

like `globalShortcut.register("CmdOrCtrl+numsub", () => false);`

ref : https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/accelerator